# Chain of inequlities in Complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I am having difficulty understanding the following inequalities which is part of a solution to a problem:
Suppose 
\begin{align}
|z-1| &< 1/2\\
|z+1|&< 5/2\\
|z|&> 1/2\\
|\sqrt{z^2+3}| &> 3/2 
\end{align}
Then we get 
$$
\frac{1}{\lvert\sqrt{z^2+3}\rvert+2}<\frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}+2}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{1}{\lvert z\rvert+\frac{1}{2}\lvert\sqrt{z^2+3}\rvert} < \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}}
$$

Comment: There should be absolute values around the Denominator in the last two lines

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't there be moduli symbols around the denominators in the third line?

If you mean $\displaystyle \frac{1}{| \sqrt{z^2+3}|+2}< \frac{1}{\frac{3}{2} + 2}$ then this is clear because $0 < A < B$ implies that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{A}>\frac{1}{B}$ along with the basic theory of inequalities. The other is proved similarly provided one is asked to show that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{| \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{z^2+3}|+|z|}< \frac{1}{\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{2}}$. In either case you don't need the other two inequalities.

Comment: Yes there should be moduli symbols around the denominators in last two lines...... Which means I am still having trouble....

Comment: But the discussion above shows you how to do it if the absolute values are in the right place...

Comment: Hi , you have it on each expression , but my problem is how to understand this if everything (last 2 denominators ) is between 2 bars ..I did not mean the modulus being on each expression ...Sorry for not being clear..